# New to iPhone Development - iOS5 Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm new here and pretty new to iOS development. My question is basically, should I learn the old school development methods or just learn how to do things using the latest tools (i.e. Storyboard)?

I've had a go with the Storyboard feature of XCode 4.2 and it's very powerful. My only concern is that it requires iOS 5. I don't mind learning the old way of doing things but I've been having trouble finding tutorials/examples for XCode 4.2 that don't use the storyboard.

An example would be the with my trouble finding a good tutorial on how to embed a Navigation Controller into a TabBarController. A lot of the material out there seems to be for older version of XCode. Using the storyboard I'm able to set this up with seconds but still haven't managed to get it working without it.

So in short :) would you guys suggest I continue my project using the Storyboard or make the extra effort to do things a little more manually?

Comment: Check out Geeky lemon they have a lot of tutorials with xibs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I'd take the extra effort and learn how to do things programmatically. There are two camps in the IOS world - those who swear by using Interface Builder, and those who hate it and do everything in code. You will eventually wind up on one side of the fence or the other, but learning how to do stuff in code will only make you a better coder. I feel much more comfortable using tools such as IB and Storyboard when I have an idea of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I don't think IB is quite that polarizing. It's very good for what it's good for, and falls down completely where it falls down. I get the sense that most experienced developers understand that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I actually agree. I've decided to go down that route and find out how to do it using code.